# Convert an opencv script

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I found this code from this website (https://www.hackster.io/tinkernut/raspberry-pi-smart-car-8641ca) and try to rewrite it so that it works with a USB webcam and not with the PI camera.
I wanted to add the recorded material to a Numpy array, but I can't get any further. After a lot of fiddling around and searching the internet I didn't find anything to solve the problem.
I don't have much experience in Python or opencv programming so I hope someone can help me because I am overwhelmed and my brain just feels like a crushed potato.
Generally to my project, I want to build an infotainment system with a Raspberry Pi and everything works except the rear view camera. So navigation, music and video playback and so on.
As main program to use all other programs I use Kodi with the CarPc-Carbonskin.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

```
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
buzzer = 22
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(buzzer, GPIO.OUT)
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (320, 240) #a smaller resolution means faster processing
camera.framerate = 24
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(320, 240))
kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
time.sleep(0.1)
for still in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
GPIO.output(buzzer, False)

image = still.array
#create a detection area
widthAlert = np.size(image, 1) #get width of image
heightAlert = np.size(image, 0) #get height of image
yAlert = (heightAlert/2) + 100 #determine y coordinates for area
cv2.line(image, (0,yAlert), (widthAlert,yAlert),(0,0,255),2) #draw a line to show area

lower = [1, 0, 20]
upper = [60, 40, 200]
lower = np.array(lower, dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array(upper, dtype="uint8")
#use the color range to create a mask for the image and apply it to the image
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

dilation = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations = 3)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(dilation, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(dilation, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
edge = cv2.Canny(closing, 175, 175)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

threshold_area = 400
centres = []

if len(contours) !=0:

    for x in contours:
        #find the area of each contour
        area = cv2.contourArea(x)
        #find the center of each contour
        moments = cv2.moments(x)
        #weed out the contours that are less than our threshold
        if area > threshold_area:

            (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(x)

            centerX = (x+x+w)/2
            centerY = (y+y+h)/2

            cv2.circle(image,(centerX, centerY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)

            if ((y+h) > yAlert):
                cv2.putText(image, "ALERT!", (centerX -20, centerY -20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255),2)
                GPIO.output(buzzer, True)

cv2.imshow("Display", image)

rawCapture.truncate(0)

key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if key == ord("q"):
    GPIO.output(buzzer, False)
    break
```

Comment: It looks like your code is not indented correctly.

Comment: maybe start from scratch and first learn how to use `cv` to get image from camera - [OpenCV-Python: Getting Started with Videos](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html). And later try to add other functions.